# Excel VBA filtered data - SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Tags: excel, vba, filter, userform

I'm having quite a trouble getting the filtered data into my userform list.

I'm trying to filter project by status being active = a, or not active  = n.

The status is in column 2 of custom table in excel. The names of projects are in column 1 of the table. Maybe it's better shown in picture:  [Picture of a list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxmsW.png)

I've tried to run this block of code

```
Worksheets("list").ListObjects("projects").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
hide_blank_cells_projekti


If active= True And not_active = True Then
        
            Worksheets("list").ListObjects("projects").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.AutoFilter _
            Field:=2, Criteria1:="a", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="n", Operator:=xlFilterValues

ElseIf active= True And not_active = False Then

            Worksheets("list").ListObjects("projects").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.AutoFilter _
            Field:=2, Criteria1:="a", Criteria2:="A", Operator:=xlFilterValues

ElseIf active= False And not_active = True Then

            Worksheets("list").ListObjects("projects").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.AutoFilter _
            Field:=2, Criteria1:="n", Criteria2:="N", Operator:=xlFilterValues

ElseIf active = False And not_active = False Then

            Worksheets("list").ListObjects("projects").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.AutoFilter _
            Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>n", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>a", Operator:=xlFilterValues

End If

'    ClearBlankCellsInColumn
project_list.List = Worksheets("list").ListObjects("projects").DataBodyRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
```

The result I got was that the list was filtered by their "a" or "n" status, but I dont get all values listed in userform list but just first few.

[Filtered values - is OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5oop.png)

[Values in userform list - is NOK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOcPC.png)

Thanks in advance for reading. Please forgive my english writing.

---

RE:
With help of @BigBen I've managed to come up with this solution.

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim projects_array() As Variant

i = 0
ReDim projects_array(i)

For Each cell In Worksheets("list").ListObjects("projects").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    If Not cell.EntireRow.Hidden Then
        projects_array(i) = cell.Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
    ReDim Preserve projects_array(i)
Next cell

ReDim Preserve projects_array(UBound(projects_array) - 1)
project_list.List = projects_array
```

Comment: You have a multi-area range with `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`. Meaning, it's composed of "chunks" of smaller ranges. You need to loop over  those.

Comment: @BigBen Than you for the answer it helped me. Rather than looking at ranges I changed to looking at all the visible cells and added those to an array. Once that worked I made array = userform list